# How can I build an e-learning platform for a nursery school/kindergarten for remote education during the COVID-19 lock down?

Tags: web-apps, academia

We come across many LMS systems out there which are built mainly for companies or higher-education/professional courses.

However, amidst the COVID-19 crisis when kindergarten kids are at home and it's all a challenge,I'm looking to implement a virtual school platform for nursery schools/kindergartens in our area.

Are there any solutions out there which cater for nursery schools and be able to offer an online platform to assist with remote student learning and communication. Virtual lessons and assignments, have students virtually respond and reflect, share class lessons/learning resources and homework, keep the discussions going and a lot more. Teachers can also conduct live video lessons. Security and confidentiality of data and information be at the core of the platform. Admin panels to allow teachers to develop lessons and content, manage and develop educational content and virtual classrooms. Admin panels for parents. Admin panels for the school management.
Basically a whole kindergarten system, online?

Comment: Something like [BlueButton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigBlueButton)? Can be self-hosted, and integrates an entire zoo as it sounds: "In addition to various web conferencing services, it has integrations for many of the major learning and content management systems." Just stumbled upon it earlier today, I'm not familiar with it myself.